# Coldfusion Query Anchor Element by Id

Tags: coldfusion

I am running a query and am try to output the information using cfoutput like this:

```
<cfoutput query="the_query">
   <p><a href="#">#QueryResult#</a><p>
</cfoutput>
```

Coldfusion won't allow me to uses the # in href. It says "Invalid CFML construct", but I need it to be href="#". Is there a way to escape this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just double up on the # character. ## inside a  tag will output a single #.

```
<cfoutput query="the_query">
   <p><a href="##">#QueryResult#</a><p>
</cfoutput>
```

No problem putting these up against regular terms, either, say you wanted to name the anchor using a field from the query:

```
   <p><a href="###QueryResultField#">#QueryResult#</a><p>
```

This would give you

```
   <p><a href="#myAnchorName">Result Here</a><p>
```

Comment: Always goods to fully qualify your variables... #the_query.queryResult#

Comment: Note that escaping hash marks (by doubling up ##) in Coldfusion must be done anytime you are inside a cfoutput tag, but not outside the cfoutput tag.