# Coldfusion: Empty Link href="#" Error

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, escaping

I am using Adobe Coldfusion Builder 3 for my CFWheels Coldfusion project.

As you know to output a variable in coldfusion you
do something like this;

```
#varaible_name#
```

However I want to use a empty link

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

and using it give me an error;

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 23 at column 46.
```

I am currently using

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

which I read is considered bad practice.

Is there any other alternative for this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To escape the `#`, you need to double it up

```
<a href="##">link</a>
```

Note: this only applies if the code is inside of `<cfoutput>` tags. If your link is outside of `<cfoutput>`, then it is left alone.

For additional examples, see: [Coldfusion Query Anchor Element by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809454/coldfusion-query-anchor-element-by-id)

Comment: Relevant docs: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/elements-of-cfml/special-characters.html